# Write lowercase letters and chars with pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I just started to learn this module pyautogui, and I already run into troubles.
I learned about the write method on [this page](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) of the docs, but for some reason, it doesn't write lowercase letters, just uppercase ones, I use Windows operating system, and tried on both Python 3.8 and Python 2.7, I didn't do any installs (other than the pip install of pyautogui), if that helps.

Comment: You may want to red [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your question, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

First Check Your CapsLock if You Press CapsLock it will write uppercase letters

otherwise try this code:

```
import pyautogui as pg

pg.typewrite('text'.lower())
```